# JQuery's load and binding functions to AjaxStart and AjaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

While learning JQuery i came across neccessity of knowing AJAX. Using python's SimpleHTTPServer i'm making experiments locally. I want to have logs in console when starting AJAX request as well as when it's complete. More precisely i have a button which got an onclick action:

```
function ddd_ajax(){
    $("#ajax_content").load("ajax_load.html")
}
```

... and a div indicating loading when starting an AJAX request:

```
$("#indic_loading").bind('ajaxSend', function(){
    $(this).show();
    console.log("Ajax START!");
    alert("Ajax START!");
}).bind('ajaxComplete', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    console.log("Ajax Complete!");
    alert("Ajax Complete!");
})
```

Unfortunately there no logs and alerts both. Maybe load() doesn't make any AJAX O_o?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to
>   document.

Example:

```
$(document).on('ajaxSend', function(){
    $("#indic_loading").show();
    console.log("Ajax START!");
    alert("Ajax START!");
}).on('ajaxComplete', function(){
    $("#indic_loading").hide();
    console.log("Ajax Complete!");
    alert("Ajax Complete!");
});
```

The reason for this is that `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` are generic events for all AJAX which take place on the page, they are not bound to any particular element as I could writing something like:

```
// No elements specified
$.ajax("mypage.html", {
    data: { param: 1 }
});
```

Instead of binding to the global events, you could just register a callback to the `.load` event:

```
function ddd_ajax(){
    console.log("AJAX Started");
    $("#ajax_content").load("ajax_load.html", function() {
        console.log("AJAX Complete");
    })
}
```